# How can I get the mouseover event to work in my Leaflet.js map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have been trying to follow [this mouseover example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) on the Leaflet.js website but I can't get [my test version](http://dev.estadaodados.com/filiados/mapa/) to work properly. The mouseover works only in some shapes at a time, but the mouseout actually never cleans the change - and the now forever-highlighted polygon becomes one of the few that the mouseover event works everytime.

This is the code I'm using:

```
window.map = L.map('map').setView([-14, -50], 5);
 L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
     id: 'teste',
     attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
 }).addTo(map);

 geojson = L.geoJson(dados,{ onEachFeature: onEachFeature }
   ).addTo(map);

 function style(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: '#800026',
            weight: 0.2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
  }
 L.geoJson(dados, {style: style}).addTo(map)

 info = L.control();
 info.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
        this.update();
        return this._div;
  };

 info.update = function (props) {
        if (props) this._div.innerHTML = '<h2>'+props.nome_ibge_ + ' - '+props.estado+'</h2><br/>' +  '<h3>'+ props.populacao_ +'</h3>';
        else this._div.innerHTML = '<h2>Passe o mouse sobre uma área</h2>'
  };
  info.addTo(map);

  function highlightFeature(e) {
      var layer = e.target;

      layer.setStyle({
          weight: 5,
          color: '#666',
          dashArray: '',
          fillOpacity: 0.7
      });

      if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
          layer.bringToFront();
      }
      info.update(layer.feature.properties);

  }

  function resetHighlight(e) {
      console.log("RESETANDO")
      geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
      info.update()
  }

  function zoomToFeature(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  }

  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
      layer.on({
          mouseover: highlightFeature,
          mouseout: resetHighlight,
          click: zoomToFeature
      });
  }
```

Comment: Your example seems to be working in Chrome.